# how to do a simple matrix transpose in openrefine

Tags: openrefine

I have data that I just need to perform a transpose on, seems simple but i can't make heads or tails of the transpose function.

data looks like this

name, requirement_1, requirement_2, requirement_3
label, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
threshold, 10, 20, 30
objective, 100, 200, 300
floor, 0, .5, .5

I need:

name, label, threshold, objective, floor
requirement_1, 1.1, 10, 100, 0
requirement_2, 1.2, 20, 200, 0.5
requirement_3, 1.3, 30, 300, 0.5

in power query this is simply clicking the transpose button.

Thanks

Comment: Any whishes regarding whtat tools we can use?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more complicated in OpenRefine, since you have to perform two operations: transpose cells across columns into rows, then columnize by key value.

[image]